# Vb.net send key combo to windows app

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I would like to send <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> to my VB.Net WinForms application. My code below does not work. Please help:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    SendKeys.Send("^+({ADD})")
End Sub
```

Comment: I would try `SendKeys.Send("^(+({ADD}))")`

Comment: According to documentation {ADD} is specifically the + sign on the keypad. I would also try {+} instead.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx#remarksToggle), <kbd>+</kbd> should be represented as `{+}`.

In addition, as I read the documentation, you can combine <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> for a single key without needing to encompass each key in parentheses. You only need parentheses if combining these modifier keys with multiple keys.

> To specify keys combined with **any combination of the SHIFT, CTRL, and ALT keys**, precede the key code with **one or more** of the following codes.

For example, if you wanted to press and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> while pressing <kbd>A</kbd> and then <kbd>B</kbd>, you'd use `^+(AB)`.
*(`^+AB` would produce <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, then release the modifier keys and press <kbd>B</kbd>.)*

Since you only want to press <kbd>+</kbd>, I believe the following should work:

```
SendKeys.Send("^+{+}")
```